# Typescript: reduce on array of objects returns concat

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am trying to get the sum of integers from an array of objects stored in a redux slice, the code is as follows:

```
export type Expense = {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    amount: number;
    date: string;
};

type ExpensesState = {
    expenses: Expense[];
};

const initialState: ExpensesState = {
expenses: [],
};
```

my reduce function is like so:

```
const total = expenses.reduce(
    (accumulator, expense) => accumulator + expense.amount,
    0
);
```

I believe it is the type of my array of objects that is causing the issue as the below example returns the sum of values in an array of objects:

```
const items = [{foo: 'bar', amount: 1}, {foo: 'bar', amount: 12}]
const total = items.reduce((acc, i) => acc + i.amount, 0)
console.log(total) // 13
```

the type of items in the above is:
type items = {
foo: string,
amount: number
}[]

however if I change the array type I am having my problem with to reflect the items type to the below, I still get a concatenation of the amounts and not the sum:

```
export type Expense = {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    amount: number;
    date: string;
}[];
```

Please help! I am going loopy!

Comment: What is the shape of expenses in runtime? Does it match the `Expense` type? For example is `typeof expenses[0].amount` a `'number'`? Most likely the amounts are strings - the question is how expense instances are produced.

Comment: Attach a debugger and check your types. Most certainly at least one of your elements has `amount` as a string. That's why it's concatenating instead of adding

Comment: one of my amounts was a string indeed

Answer (score 0):

so in the end there were two problems with the code above:

**Problem one:**

One of my amount elements was a string, deleting this object from my array solved the issue of concatenation, reduce will concatenate if the property is a string.

**Problem two**

After the fix in problem one my reducer was returning an object to work on next, after some debugging I realised the issue is with what I am returning from the callback, reduce will use the return result from the first callback for the next value to work on.

The issue with my code is I am then trying to access the return result with:

```
const total = items.reduce((acc, i) => acc + i.amount, 0)
```

the problem here is that `acc` is an object! I should be returning an object with the amount property to do the calculation like so:

```
const total = expenses.reduce((accumulator, expense) => ({
    ...expense,
    amount: accumulator.amount + expense.amount,
}));
```

notice the spreading of the `expense` object also, this is needed as the `expenses` object has properties that the newly created accumulator object was missing.

With the amendments outlined above I get the desired result (a total sum of all the amounts in my array of objects)